# New button is not added in the jqgrid at the top using fontawesome icons

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to add a new icon(move) in jqgrid at the top of the table.I am using jqgrid version 5.2.I have used fontawesome icons but the new icon is not added.

```
$("#list1").jqGrid(
                "navGrid",
                "#prowed1",
                {
                    formatter : 'actions',
                    cloneToTop:true,
                    add : true,
                    edit : true,
                    del : true,
                    search : true,
                    view : false,
                    refresh : true,
                },);
jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid',"#prowed1").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#prowed1",{
            cloneToTop:true,
            caption: "",
            buttonicon:'fa fa-arrows',
            onClickButton:null,
            position: "last", 
            title:"", 
            cursor: "pointer"
        });
```

I have used iconSet:"fontAwesome".prowes1 is the name of pager .What is the error?

Comment: "jqGrid" product exists only till the version 4.7. After that there are two main forks: commercial "Guriddo jqGrid JS" (the last released version is 5.2.1) and "free jqGrid" (the last released version is 4.14.1). You uses currently **commercial** "Guriddo jqGrid JS" 5.2.0 (see the license and prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). The option `iconSet:"fontAwesome"`, which you tried to use is the option of "free jqGrid" (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data)), but not in Guriddo.

Comment: So how can I add the another button(move) using fontawesome with larger size?

Comment: I can help you only with **free jqGrid**, which I develop, and not with **alternative** fork Guriddo jqGrid JS. The usage of `navButtonAdd` is very simple in free jqGrid: see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9f9exg91/13/.

Comment: Guriddo jqGrid JS is not a alternative fork, **free** jqGrid is a **fork** as can be seen.

Comment: Sorry to post again, here is a proof which [jqGrid is a fork](http://www.guriddo.net/pictures/jqGridFork.png) -

Comment: @TonyTomov: I saw by chance your last comments. To be exact both products "Guriddo jqGrid JS" and "free jqGrid" are forks of another product: "jqGrid". You changed license agreement and you sell "Guriddo jqGrid JS" [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) **without confirmation** from [other contributors](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/graphs/contributors) of jqGrid repository. Thus, de facto "Guriddo jqGrid JS" is do the fork of jqGrid, but the problem is: **you publish "Guriddo jqGrid JS" in GitHub under the same repository, where you published jqGrid before**.

Answer (score 0):

Custom added buttons are not added automatically to the top pager when cloneToTop is on. Please consult the [Guridoo documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/navigating/)

Look at *cloneToTop* option

Comment: Then what should I use?

Comment: You will need to add a custom button at the top pager. For this purpose use another navButtonAdd method with pager id described into the docs which I have provided (see cloneToTop option)